# How to filter out all rows matching a certain ID when a variable in one row is 'X'? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, nested, aggregate

First off, I'm sorry if the wording of this is bad or incorrect, I'm trying my best.

But anyway, to try to make things simple as possible, I am trying to generate a report of messages that have not been read. So there is a communications table that links to the comm_recpts table where there is a "Has_read_msg" field.

The issue is, these communications are sometimes being routed to a few different users. Therefore, the "has_read_msg" field only updates to "y" for the individual user that has read the message. So if even one user has read the message, I don't want this message at all on my report.

If that wasn't clear, what I am currently getting is all the USERS that haven't read the message, but if the message was read by someone, I don't want them on there. I still want the users names on my report though (If the message wasn't read by anyone).

Here's what I have so far, if it helps at all...

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.comm_id, c.sender_id, p.last_name, p.first_name, p.date_of_birth, 
  CASE WHEN(rec.last_name+', '+rec.first_name) IS NULL 
      THEN r.name 
    ELSE (rec.last_name+', '+rec.first_name) 
    END 'Recipient',
  r.has_read_msg, r.recipient_type, r.recipient_id,  c.sender_type, c.create_timestamp, 
  r.has_read_msg, c.replied_when, c.delete_ind, c.priority_flag, c.subject, 
  c.body
FROM ngweb_communications c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN person p 
    ON c.sender_id=CONVERT(varchar(50),p.person_id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ngweb_comm_recpts r 
    ON c.comm_id=r.comm_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_mstr rec 
    ON r.recipient_id=CONVERT(varchar(50),rec.user_id)
WHERE 1=1
  AND c.sender_type=2
  AND r.has_read_msg='N'
  AND c.body NOT LIKE 'This message was read by%'
ORDER BY c.create_timestamp desc
```

I have tried nested statements and aggregate functions, but haven't been able to get it to work yet...

Like I said I'm trying my best to word this, but if I can clarify at all, or share anymore info, please let me know.

I am using SQL Server 2008...thanks to anyone even taking a look at this!

Comment: What would really help is the table structure and some sample data. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

using `not exists()`:

```
select distinct 
    c.comm_id
  , c.sender_id
  , p.last_name
  , p.first_name
  , p.date_of_birth
  , Recipient = isnull(rec.last_name + ', ' + rec.first_name,r.name) 
  , r.has_read_msg
  , r.recipient_type
  , r.recipient_id
  , c.sender_type
  , c.create_timestamp
  , r.has_read_msg
  , c.replied_when
  , c.delete_ind
  , c.priority_flag
  , c.subject
  , c.body
from ngweb_communications c
  left join person p
    on c.sender_id = convert(varchar(50), p.person_id)
  left join ngweb_comm_recpts r 
    on c.comm_id = r.comm_id
  left join user_mstr rec
    on r.recipient_id = convert(varchar(50), rec.user_id)
where 1 = 1
  and c.sender_type = 2
  and r.has_read_msg = 'N'
  and c.body not like 'This message was read by%'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from ngweb_communications ic
      inner join ngweb_comm_recpts ir
        on ic.comm_id = ir.comm_id
    where ic.comm_id = c.comm_id
      and ir.has_read_msg = 'Y'
      )
order by c.create_timestamp desc
```

Notes & Questions:

- I replaced your `case` statement with `isnull()` for simplicity. `coalesce()` would also work in the same manner.
- Do not use string literals for aliases.
- Why are you converting ids to `varchar(50)` for equality comparison? This has significant detrimental impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line in your WHERE clause:

```
AND r.has_read_msg='N'
```

With this:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (Select 1 FROM ngweb_comm_recpts rx WHERE rx.comm_id = c.comm_id AND rx.has_read_msg = 'Y')
```